# AngularJs: ui.router does not loading controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'l try to use AngularJs with ui.router, but have the trouble.

This example have three states: index, template and template.show

```
$stateProvider
  .state('/', {
    url: '',
    template: '<a ui-sref="template">GoTo Template Index</a>'
  })
  .state('template', {
    url: 'template',
    templateUrl: 'template_index.html',
    controller: 'TemplateCtrl'
  })
  .state('template.show', {
    url: '/{templateId:[0-9]+}',
    templateUrl: 'template_show.html',
    controller: 'TemplateShowCtrl'
  })
```

Please, see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/prluQs9vXeJw9IVi2JYW?p=info

But only two first states working. State "template.show" changing, loading template, but does **not execute** TemplateShowCtrl and **not update** ui-view to new template.

You can see [screenshot](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=4iooxy&s=8#.VMmq6ZMppdw)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any child state requires the presence of a subsequent `ui-view` directive in its parent so that it knows where to insert the html. Currently, there is not one present in the `template_index.html` markup.

It should instead look something akin to this:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="t in templates">
     <a ui-sref="template.show({templateId:t.id})" href='#'>
       {{t.name}}
     </a>
   </li>
</ul>
<!-- target element -->
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought, that content will be replaced by new template